# How to delete row from table build in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html

I built a table from JSON object then retrieve it and build table automatically from its content. Then I added a new column contains buttons (using js) to delete each row individually. How I can delete certain row depending on each row id?

table.js

```
$(document).ready(function (){
var json = [
    {
    "id": "0",
    "firstName":"Ahmed",
    "lastName":"Mahmoud",
    "Email": "ahmed.m92@gmail.com",
    "Phone": "0599547632",
    "Type": "Male"},
    {
    "id": "1",
    "firstName":"Mahmoud",
    "lastName":"Qasem",
    "Email": "m.Qasem80@gmail.com",
    "Phone": "0599547632",
    "Type" : "Male"},

    {
    "id": "2",
    "firstName":"Lena",
    "lastName":"Asaed",
    "Email": "lena_ahmed@hotmail.com",
    "Phone": "0599547632",
    "Type": "Female"}
];
        var tr;
        var buttonnode= document.createElement('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');

            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id +"</td>");
            tr.append("<td >" + json[i].id +"</td>");
            tr.append("<td >" + json[i].firstName +"</td>");
            tr.append("<td >" + json[i].lastName + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td >" + json[i].Email + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td >" + json[i].Phone + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td >" + json[i].Type + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td >"+'<button id="delete" >Delete</button>'+"</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNYqp.png)
This is a snapshot of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt test it, but you could do it like this:

```
var table = $("table");

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var row = "<tr id='row-" + i + "'>";
    row += "<td>" + json[i].id +"</td>";
    row += "<td>" + json[i].firstName +"</td>";
    row += "<td>" + json[i].lastName + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + json[i].Email + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + json[i].Phone + "</td>";
    row += "<td>" + json[i].Type + "</td>";
    row += "<td><button onClick='deleteRow(" + i +")'>Delete</button></td>";
    row += "</tr>";
    table.append(row);
}

function deleteRow(rowId){
    table.find("td#row-" + rowId).remove();
}
```

For larger tables i highly recommend using a framework like AngularJS which makes it easy to keep your markup simple and implement functions to modify your table.

```
// edit: if you want to use the original ID of your JSON you can just replace the counter with the JSON objects ID
var row = "<tr id='row-" + json[i].id + "'>";
```

Update: The jQuery way without "onclick":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var table = $("table");

  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      var row = "<tr id='row-" + i + "'>";
      row += "<td>" + json[i].id +"</td>";
      row += "<td>" + json[i].firstName +"</td>";
      row += "<td>" + json[i].lastName + "</td>";
      row += "<td>" + json[i].Email + "</td>";
      row += "<td>" + json[i].Phone + "</td>";
      row += "<td>" + json[i].Type + "</td>";
      row += "<td><button class='remove-button' data-id='" + i + "'>Delete</button></td>";
      row += "</tr>";
      table.append(row);
  };

  $(".remove-button").click(function(){
    var rowId = $(this).data("id");
    $("#row-" + rowId).remove();
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvvbfr4j/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I test it and keep give me "deleteRow is not defined" ?!

Comment: I updated my answer with a tested jQuery like solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate your efforts